# How to get rid of the `as any` in this code, without making it verbose

Tags: typescript

The code below works fine, but the use of `as any` is not ideal, is there another pattern that is also not verbose, which achieves a similar outcome?

```js
const defaultError = 'error'

type Options = { error: string } | { errorFn: ()=>string } | {}

function parse(options: Options={}){
    return {
        errorFn: (options as any).errorFn || (()=>(options as any).error||defaultError)
    }
}

console.log(parse({ error: 'hello' }).errorFn())
console.log(parse({ errorFn: ()=>'world'}).errorFn())
console.log(parse().errorFn())
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwGYEMCuAbKBRATrkXGAXhgHIF9CyAoGqATwAcEYB5JqAS3AhJgDeMSgVwAuGNFxcwAcxgBfGAB9BwqrgBiYCQAoAlMQB8UmfKWqBCukjRhg3cDCYpcEBLpCcekCR0eQxFb6AjQw4TC4CFBouGCCYRFJIoTael4BfChZYAz6AHQpWvHKqroGxp7evDDZtbkFRaWIqJg4GvqJ4dbWNKCQIBgI+Rggsroubh5CRRJkABYIGKNkio0a2gad-RCDw6Pjk+66Mxs6MBVGZADuhBhwZArropv627x7I2MTrsfPqWAtkA)

Comment: How verbose is "verbose"? Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wezedN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: thank you, yes that's probably the best solution.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance; it's my bedtime now so probably 8ish hours from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just write

```
options.errorFn || (() => options.error || defaultError)
```

without compiler errors because technically a value of type `Options` can have any property type at the `errors` or `errorFn` keys:

```
type Options = { error: string } | { errorFn: () => string } | {}
const hmm = { error: 123, errorFn: 456 };
const opts: Options = hmm; // no compiler error here, this is allowed
```

Object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extendible* and can always support extra properties not mentioned in their definitions, not *closed* or *exact*.  A value of type `{error: string}` must have a `string`-valued `error` property, but it *may* have any other property also.  If TypeScript had exact types as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) then maybe `Exact<{ error: string }>` would allow you to say that the only property that exists is `error`, and that any other property read would result in `undefined`.  But we can't say that.

So, again technically, your `Options` type allows any non-nullish value whatsoever, since it's a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) including the empty `{}` type which allows just about everything except `null` and `undefined`.  And so any implementation of `parse` should theoretically require something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to let you proceed because the compiler can't guarantee that the presence of `errorFn`, even if it's of type `function`, would behave the way you expect:

```
const uhOh = { errorFn(x: string) { return x.toUpperCase() } }
const oopsie: Options = uhOh;
parse(oopsie).errorFn() // RUNTIME ERROR, x is undefined
```

**If you can change `Options`** so that it can't accept anything-at-any-property, then you can do so in a way which makes your code easy to write and safe to use.  For example:

```
type Options = { error?: string, errorFn?: () => string }
```

Now an `Options`'s `error` property is either `string` or missing/undefined, and its `errorFn` property is either a zero-arg-function-returning-`string` or missing/undefined.  It is not allowable to assign random things to these properties anymore:

```
const hmm = { error: 123, errorFn: 456 };
const opts: Options = hmm; // error!

const uhOh = { errorFn(x: string) { return x.toUpperCase() } }
const oopsie: Options = uhOh; // error!
```

And so then `parse()` becomes simple to write:

```
function parse(options: Options = {}) {
    return {
        errorFn: options.errorFn || (() => options.error || defaultError); // okay
    }
}
```

That compiles because `options.errorFn` is known to be `(()=>string) | undefined`, and the [short-circuiting of the logical OR (`||`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation) is tracked by the type system, leading the returned object to be of type `{errorFn: ()=>string}`.

So this would be my suggestion if you can change `Options`.

---

If you *can't* change `Options` then you can use [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), which treats unions as if they were exact types. For example, if you check `"errorFn" in options`, then the compiler will use that to narrow `options` to `{errorFn: ()=>string}` if true and to `{error: string} | {}` if false:

```
function parse(options: Options = {}) {
    return {
        errorFn: "errorFn" in options ? options.errorFn :
            () => "error" in options ? options.error : defaultError
    } // no compiler error here
}
```

That lets you move forward.

But again, doing such narrowing is technically unsafe. This version of `parse()` has the same uncaught runtime error with

```
const uhOh = { errorFn(x: string) { return x.toUpperCase() } }
const oopsie: Options = uhOh;
parse(oopsie).errorFn() // RUNTIME ERROR, x is undefined
```

So what's the difference?  It turns out that `in` operator narrowing is intentionally unsafe, as per [a comment by the TS team lead](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065#issuecomment-643826453) in [microsoft/TypeScript#39065](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065):

> [T]his pattern is not safe to use because object types aren't closed, so the existence of a value in some property slot is really not a solid indication that anything correct is happening. *The `in` operator is granted an exception to this because there's nothing else you might be intending to do with the `in` operator* [emphasis added]."

So the TS team takes the position that this is an acceptable safety hole, because `"errorFn" in options` is unambiguously meant by the developer as a way to narrow `options`, while `options.errorFn` might be written for other reasons and so the former narrows while the latter does not.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=48&pln=14&pc=47#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YECCMYCcD2CAFkgN4BQSlS8ewUALkgCYQBmIArgDb0CiO+HEgC8SAOQQBeHGLIUq9AJ4xkKGPQCWtKCNJJJggPwAuJAxwbgAcwA0+qTgBiwE0gAUAShEA+M-QvWSAC+clTU2oyEYGC6JPaCpgCMAEwAzHYG0s6mACwArABswQDc8pQ0dIx46lCmapraulFgxUgA9G3x0gCEoVQVDEgchCjEonGZTsBuAB6m5pZWXnE4EPQcOMBIMwB09HgAqtiSAMIgUBCewcFl4ZVIeNVQGhB16lp0usOjrR1dOL1bqwOMB4A0tnAcBc3NVwbVUO9GuMgstbmFVutNqQ0WEqJNsg9EXQdvitgAfMnuK7CXywj5QEkOJAU5hsTg8fiCDy-Tp4ADWIEUOMoITCIVuAzwXAgOy4eCsbkh0ImDlMYkIEC4crEwQ8jMEzk8Hgl2ilMrlCqVlxVBuApmpvjEAHdpFwmDqUfqstMPMawpLpbL5YqQFDLnrSUa5CFQJBYAhkBhgHh6BqcFhcAR4MRyP6Iqz2Nw+EzRBIHLJbkoVAi4bF-vN-ItrpSbd77V4aX4AlZm6RRf188065MkmkMg4CfkikFSnn7rD4fV6U1ojyHgKhXIgSCwR8kFaYUTF0fYijsbiqBiNltcxfcaTTAAiUmPpCWQm1wwf+leqZIYzCnelAOkgz4OK+750o0X5QcSkz-gW7LFoIgH9iKfTlKagYWiGYZuK2OBqhqWp4B6EYTj6foDnQZpBpaobKv8BIgc6rrurqv6Gr6Jo0dhwYHuRtpRhhdyDN8Yx6JGcxdosyxIFeWK7PsRwqDgZzQl4QQ3HOgyPDAzyvDWy6iOJs5UAeekGYJ3pXH8ABKBwAHIACoAJIALK8EgvB2XZKB2XYMxvjoIIsKwlgQEw0ZAA)